# complex.h does not working ,why?

Tags: c

I have vs 2013 and i'm trying to run this code i'm guessing that my compiler does'nt support one of those commands below, sombody know what kind of compiler can i download that those commands will work (c code).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #include <complex.h>

    void main()
    {
    float complex var, op;
        printf(" Enter the number : ");
        scanf("%lf", &var);
        op = csqrt(var);
        printf("%lf \n", op);
    }
```

There is an eror - "var" is undefined .

Comment: While msvc 2013 comes with the complex.h header, the msvc C compiler doesn't not support `float complex`

Comment: So what kind of compiler support this command , and can i download it?, it's a long program i want to do it as simple as possible.

Comment: 1) https://www.eclipse.org/ supports complex  2) BTW %lf is for `double`, not `float complex`.